# Spaceship movement

Tags: javascript, raphael, game-physics

I am creating a mini space ship game with a feel similar to escape velocity. I cannot seem to get inertia to work correctly.
I am also having problems with the turning functions. If I tap the left or right arrow keys then it does not follow anything similar to the circular type movement that should be happening.

```
$(function() {
var canvas = Raphael('game', 1000, 800);
var background = canvas.rect(0, 0, 1000, 800);
background.attr("fill", "black");

var ship = canvas.rect(200, 200, 10, 35);
ship.attr("fill", "red");
ship.angle = 0;
ship.turnrate = 4;
ship.maxSpeed = 2;
ship.acc = 0;
ship.accSpeed = 0.25;
ship.vel = [0,0];

var up = 0;
var left = 0;
var right = 0;
var speedx = 0;
var speedy = 0;

function moveShip() {
    if (left == 1) {
        ship.angle = (ship.angle - ship.turnrate) % 360;
    }

    if (right == 1) {
        ship.angle = (ship.angle + ship.turnrate) % 360;
    }

    if (up == 1) {
        if (ship.acc < ship.maxSpeed) {
            ship.acc += ship.accSpeed;
        }

        if (ship.acc > ship.maxSpeed) {
            ship.acc = ship.speed;
        }
    }

    if (up == 0) {
        if (ship.acc > 0) {
            ship.acc -= ship.accSpeed;
        }

        if (ship.acc < 0) {
            ship.acc = 0;
        }
    }

    speedx = ship.vel[0] + ship.acc * Math.sin(ship.angle);
    speedy = ship.vel[1] + ship.acc * Math.cos(ship.angle);

    ship.vel = [speedx, speedy];

    ship.transform("");
    ship.rotate(ship.angle);
    ship.attr({x: ship.vel[0], y: ship.vel[1]});

    $("#stats").text("ship.angle: " + ship.angle
            + " vel[0]: " + ship.vel[0] + " vel[1]: " + ship.vel[1]
    + " ship.speed: " + ship.maxSpeed + " speedx: " + speedx + " speedy: " + speedy);
}

function keyPressed(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
        up = 1;
    }

    if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
        left = 1;
    }

    if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
        right = 1;
    }
}

function keyReleased(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
        up = 0;
    }

    if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
        left = 0;
    }

    if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
        right = 0;
    }
}

function gameloop() {
    moveShip();
}

$(document).keydown(keyPressed);
$(document).keyup(keyReleased);
setInterval(gameloop, 30);
});
```

I have been searching stack overflow and the internet, but most questions out there are to do with the classic Space Invaders type game which does not involve turning or inertia.

Any help would be appreciated, I really just want to have a good understanding of what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to change the acceleration of a ship with the arrow keys? Remember, acceleration is the rate of change of the velocity. This means, if you have a constant acceleration then you velocity will start to grow and grow and grow. Pretty soon you will have a ship that is going way too fast.

The results from the chatroom, here for posterity:

```
$(function() {
    var canvas = Raphael('game', 1000, 800);
    var background = canvas.rect(0, 0, 1000, 800);
    background.attr("fill", "black");

    var ship = canvas.rect(200, 200, 10, 35);
    ship.attr("fill", "red");
    ship.angle = 0;
    ship.turnrate = 4;
    ship.maxSpeed = 0.25;
    ship.acc = 0.25;
    ship.vel = [0,0];
    ship.pos = [500,400];

    var up = 0;
    var left = 0;
    var right = 0;
    var speedx = 0;
    var speedy = 0;

    function moveShip() {
        if (left == 1) {
            ship.angle = (ship.angle - ship.turnrate) % 360;
        }

        if (right == 1) {
            ship.angle = (ship.angle + ship.turnrate) % 360;
        }

        if (up == 1) {
            speedx = ship.vel[0] + ship.acc * Math.sin(ship.angle * Math.PI / 180);
            speedy = ship.vel[1] - ship.acc * Math.cos(ship.angle * Math.PI / 180);

            ship.vel = [speedx, speedy];
        }
        ship.pos = [ship.pos[0] + speedx, ship.pos[1] + speedy];

        ship.transform("");
        ship.rotate(ship.angle);
        ship.attr({x: ship.pos[0], y: ship.pos[1]});

        $("#stats").text("ship.angle: " + ship.angle
                + " vel[0]: " + ship.vel[0] + " vel[1]: " + ship.vel[1]
        + " ship.speed: " + ship.maxSpeed + " speedx: " + speedx + " speedy: " + speedy);
    }

    function keyPressed(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
            up = 1;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
            left = 1;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
            right = 1;
        }
    }

    function keyReleased(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 38) {
            up = 0;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
            left = 0;
        }

        if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
            right = 0;
        }
    }

    function gameloop() {
        moveShip();
    }

    $(document).keydown(keyPressed);
    $(document).keyup(keyReleased);
    setInterval(gameloop, 30);
});​
```

There were two bugs fixed. A `pos` attribute was added, so that velocity and position can be updated separately. Also, `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` take angles in radians, so we converted the angle for those functions.

You can play with the results: http://jsfiddle.net/mJcN7/8/

Comment: I think I need ship.accSpeed so that I can control inertia, not sure how else I would do it. Also do you know if there is anything wrong with the speedx or speedy variables? The ship still turns in completely unexpected ways.

Comment: Inertia is the resistance of an object to change its velocity. Momentum is a quantity that is equal to mass times velocity, and which is conserved so long as there is no external force applied (such as from a ship's engine). So to model momentum, all you need to do is keep a ship's velocity constant between frames. To model inertia, you need to make sure that the ship doesn't change velocity too much too quickly, which you can do by making acceleration a small constant. Since there's a lot to digest, why don't you join this chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7722/spaceship-physics